# presentTextInputControllerでsiriが起動しない

Tags: swift, watchkit

**前提・実現したいこと**
Apple Watchで音声入力を使用したアプリの作成をしています。
ボタンを押すと、音声入力画面が立ち上がるというシンプルな仕様です。

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**
ボタンを押すと、音声入力画面に遷移するのですが、そこで音声入力機能が立ち上がりません。
左上にcancelボタンだけ表示され、他は真っ黒で音声を認識してくれません。

**該当のソースコード**

```
@IBAction func recordMemo() {
    presentTextInputController(withSuggestions: nil, allowedInputMode: .plain, completion: {(results) -> Void in
    let aResult = results?[0] as? String
    print(aResult as Any)
}) 
}
```

**試したこと**
海外の記事なども色々みましたが、どうしても原因がわかりません。
よろしくお願いします。

**補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）**
以下のようなエラーメッセージがでています。

```
Dictation is not supported in the WatchKit Simulator
```

ただ、withSuggestionsをnilではなく文字配列にすると音声入力も受け付けてくれます。

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/143788

Comment: 実機でテストしたら正常に起動しました。シミュレーターの仕様か、不具合のようです。